# Foundation Top Bar won't snap correctly

Tags: javascript, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to get foundations navbar working, but somehow it won't work.
It snaps about 250px too early. Just scroll down, the scroll bar should get sticky on top once it hits the top.

Javascript and CSS is loaded correctly.

I'm using Foundation 4.2.2 btw :)

The website I'm talking about:
http://gaumengut.lucid-lemon.com/index.php

Comment: How does it break? It seems fine to me (Windows 7; Firefox 22.0/IE 10).

Comment: Same as @jsalonen, looked good in webkit, OSX.

Comment: it should just snap when it's hitting the top, not 200px before the top? I don't get the wished result with chrome, safari and FF within osx AND windows. See my working example here: www.danielwinter.at